# AppScript: 'number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range.' setValues method not reading array correctly?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automate the collection of phone numbers from an API into a Google Sheet with app script. I can get the data and place it in an array with the following code:

```
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      Accept: 'Application/JSON',
  }
  };
var serviceUrl = "dummyurl.com/?params";
 var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);
  if(data.getResponseCode() == 200) {
   var response = JSON.parse(data.getContentText());
    if (response !== null){
      var keys = Object.keys(response.call).length;
      var phoneArray = [];
      for(i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
           phoneArray.push(response.call[i].caller.caller_id);
      }
```

This works as expected - it grabs yesterday's caller ID values from a particular marketing campaign from my API. Next, I want to import this data into a column in my spreadsheet. To do this, I use the setValues method like so:

```
      Logger.log(phoneArray);
      var arrayWrapper = [];
      arrayWrapper.push(phoneArray);
      Logger.log(arrayWrapper);

      for(i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        var cell = sheet.getRange("A8");
        cell.setValues(arrayWrapper);


      }
    }
 }
}
```

I am aware that I need my array length to equal the length of the selected range of cells in my sheet. However, I get conflicting errors depending on the length I set for my getRange method. If I set it to a single cell, as you see above, the error I get is:

> The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 8 but the range has 1.

However, if I set the length of my range to 8 (or any value except 1), I get the error:

> The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 8.

As you see, the error swaps values. Now I have the appropriate number of columns in the range, but my script only finds 1 cell of data. When I check the log, I see that my 2D array looks normal in both cases - 8 phone numbers in an array wrapped in another array.

What is causing this error? I cannot find reference to similar errors on SO or elsewhere.

Also, please note that I'm aware this code is a little wonky (weird variables and two for loops where one would do). I've been troubleshooting this for a couple hours and was originally using setValue instead of setValues. While trying to debug it, things got split up and moved around a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to make this work, though I can't speak to *why* the error is occurring, or rather why one receives reversed error messages depending on the setRange value.

Rather than pushing the whole list of values from the API to phoneArray, I structured my first for loop to reset the value of phoneArray each loop and push a single value array to my arrayWrapper, like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
        var phoneArray = [];
        var phoneNumber = response.call[i].caller.caller_id;
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/-/g,'');
        phoneArray.push(phoneNumber);
        arrayWrapper.push(phoneArray);
      }
```

Note that I also edited the formatting of the phone numbers to suit my needs, so I pulled each value into a variable to make replacing a character simple. What this new for loop results in is a 2D array like so:

```
[[1235556789],[0987776543],[0009872345]]
```

Rather than what I had before, which was like this:

```
[[1235556789,0987776543,0009872345]]
```

It would appear that this is how the setValues method wants its data structured, although [the documentation suggests otherwise.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Regardless, if anyone were to run into similar issues, this is the gist of what must be done to fix it, or at least the method I found worked. I'm sure there are far more performant and elegant solutions than mine, but I will be dealing with dozens of rows of data, not thousands or millions. Performance isn't a big concern for me.

Answer (score 2):

- The dimension of your range is one row and several columns
- If you push an array into another array, the dimension will be `[[...],[...],[...]]` - i.e. you have one column and multiple rows
- What you want instead is one row and multiple columns:  `[[...,...,...]]`
- To achieve this you need to create a two-dimensional array and push all entries into the first row of your array: `phoneArray[0]=[]; phoneArray[0].push(...);`

### Sample:

```
  var phoneArray = [];
  phoneArray[0]=[];
  for(i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
        var phoneNumber = response.call[i].caller.caller_id;
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/-/g,'');
        phoneArray[0].push(phoneNumber);
      }
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,8,1, keys);
  range.setValues(phoneArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var correct = [[data],[data]]`  -
is the data structure that is required for `setValues()`

therefore

`?.setValues(correct)`