# Google AppScript can't match number of columns in data with number of columns in range

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527707/appscript-number-of-columns-in-the-data-does-not-match-the-number-of-columns-i), but when I try to apply their solution, it does not work for my data.

I am trying to write a script that downloads data from an API and puts it into a spreadsheet. The data comes in the form of a nested array ​`[[.,.,.], [.,.,.]]​` where each sub-array should eventually be one row of data. The number of rows should be the length of the overall array and the number of columns should be the length of one of the nested arrays.

When I try to feed it into the line ​`thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)`​ I get an error that says the number of columns in my data does not match the number of columns in the range.

When I try to use the push method explained in the linked post, I end up getting a triple nested array that looks like `[[[.,.,.], [.,.,.]]]`.

How can I ​match up the values so that I can input my data into the spreadsheet?

Comment: From your question, I understood that you wanted to convert your value to a 2-dimensional array. Is my understanding correct? But, unfortunately, I cannot imagine your sample value. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input values?

Comment: First, try to log and check the length of each row. `const length = data[0].length; data.forEach((row, i) => { if (row.length !== length) console.log(i, row.length, row) })`

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: By guessing your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: With a sample array `var data= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` setting the values like `getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)` does work. However, if not all of the inner arrays have the same length, then you will encounter that error, in which case I think Tanaike's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75335691/12306687) is the best solution to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I guessed your question as follows.

- Your sample input value is as follows. In this sample, the length of each array in the 2-dimensional array is different.

  ```json
  [
    ["sample", "sample", "sample"],
    ["sample", "sample", "sample", "sample", "sample"],
    ["sample", "sample"],
    ["sample", "sample", "sample", "sample"],
  ]
  ```
- You want to convert the above array as follows. You want to convert the length of all arrays to the same length.

  ```json
  [
    ["sample", "sample", "sample", "", ""],
    ["sample", "sample", "sample", "sample", "sample"],
    ["sample", "sample", "", "", ""],
    ["sample", "sample", "sample", "sample", ""],
  ]
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const sampleArray = [
  ["sample", "sample", "sample"],
  ["sample", "sample", "sample", "sample", "sample"],
  ["sample", "sample"],
  ["sample", "sample", "sample", "sample"],
];

const maxLen = Math.max(...sampleArray.map(r => r.length));
const res = sampleArray.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill("")]);
console.log(res);
```

- When this script is run, the above result value is obtained.

#### Note:

- In order to put the values to the Spreadsheet, in this case, I think that `fill("")` can be also replaced with `fill(null)`.
- As the additional information, for example, when ["Method: spreadsheets.values.update"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) of Sheets API is used, even when the length of each array in the 2-dimensional array is different, the values can be put to the spreadsheet using the array.

  ```
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: sampleArray }, spreadsheetId, "Sheet1", { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you so much! I am fairly new to Javascript though, can you please explain why I need the `...` in front of `sampleArray`, `r`, and `Array`?

Comment: @Jon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `the ... in front of sampleArray, r, and Array`, `...` is the spread syntax. You can see the document at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). In the case of `[...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill("")]`, each element of `r` (an array) is concatenated with the empty elements in order to embed the gap of each length. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.